# Keras - custom loss function - chamfer distance

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am attempting object segmentation using a custom loss function as defined below:

```
def chamfer_loss_value(y_true, y_pred):           

    # flatten the batch 
    y_true_f = K.batch_flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.batch_flatten(y_pred)

    # ==========
    # get chamfer distance sum

    // error here
    y_pred_mask_f = K.cast(K.greater_equal(y_pred_f,0.5), dtype='float32')

    finalChamferDistanceSum = K.sum(y_pred_mask_f * y_true_f, axis=1, keepdims=True)  

    return K.mean(finalChamferDistanceSum)

def chamfer_loss(y_true, y_pred):   
    return chamfer_loss_value(y_true, y_pred)
```

`y_pred_f` is the result of my U-net. `y_true_f` is the result of a euclidean distance transform on the ground truth label mask `x` as shown below:

```
distTrans = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(1 - x)
```

To compute the Chamfer distance, you multiply the predicted image (ideally, a mask with 1 and 0) with the ground truth distance transform, and simply sum over all pixels. To do this, I needed to get a mask `y_pred_mask_f` by thresholding `y_pred_f`, then multiply with `y_true_f`, and sum over all pixels.

`y_pred_f` provides a continuous range of values in [0,1], and I get the error `None type not supported` at the evaluation of `y_true_mask_f`.  I know the loss function has to be differentiable, and `greater_equal` and `cast` are not. But, is there a way to circumvent this in Keras? Perhaps using some workaround in Tensorflow?

Comment: It's not differentiable but you need the gradient to optimize if you use gradient descend. Do you have the manually defined gradients? If so, you can manually compute the gradients and put them in. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839431/tensorflow-how-to-replace-or-modify-gradient/43948872

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this was tricky. The reason behind your error is that there is **no continuous dependence** between your loss and your network. In order to compute gradients of your loss w.r.t. to network, your loss must compute the gradient of indicator if your output is greater than `0.5` (as this is the only connection between your final loss value and output `y_pred` from your network). This is impossible as this indicator is partially constant and not continuous.

**Possible solution - smooth your indicator:**

```
def chamfer_loss_value(y_true, y_pred):           

    # flatten the batch 
    y_true_f = K.batch_flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.batch_flatten(y_pred)

    y_pred_mask_f = K.sigmoid(y_pred_f - 0.5)

    finalChamferDistanceSum = K.sum(y_pred_mask_f * y_true_f, axis=1, keepdims=True)  

    return K.mean(finalChamferDistanceSum)
```

As `sigmoid` is a continuous version of a step function. If your output comes from `sigmoid` - you could simply use `y_pred_f` instead of `y_pred_mask_f`.