# Tensorflow clipping gradients halfway through a graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `tensorflow` model.  There are some polynomial operations in the thing with high powers, and some divisions, i.e. things that take small errors and turn them into big ones.  In my model, for 99% of points, everything works out just fine.  However, 1% of the time, a small error turns into a big error, and my gradient for those few points, about midway through the graph, become `inf`.  Further up the graph, various operations on those `inf`s easily turn into `nan`s.  By the time the gradient gets up to my variables, it has fallen apart, and clipping is moot.

Anyhow, what I would like to do is to clip my gradient, or to do something else to mitigate the damage *before* it gets out of hand.  Since my gradient gets evaluated point-wise in the graph, I could even set the gradient for those problematic points to be 0 and things would move along without too much trouble.  I know the approximate location where I would need to deal with my exploding gradients.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501922/2886575), unfortunately, only seems to apply to gradients once they've made it all the way back to my variables.  Is it possible to clip gradients halfway through a graph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: How to replace or modify gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43839431). If you look at `clip_grad_layer` at the end of the accepted answer, I think it does what you want (clip a gradient at an arbitrary point in the graph).